# Query mongo collection as an object (not array)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to aggregate my collection (with mongoose) to get all documents in the following form:

```
{
   _id1: doc1,
   _id2: doc2,
   ....
}
```

instead of the usual array ([doc1, doc2, ...]). it allows me to easily access docs by their id.

Thanks!

Comment: But, you can easily access any document in the collection using its `_id` field. _or_ by any other field - that is querying.

Answer (score 0):

```
//actual code output form mongo shell
//prepare data
db.mycoll2.insertMany([
{_id:1,"docarr":["doc1","doc2","doc3"]},
{_id:2,"docarr":["doc4","doc5","doc6"]}
]
);
> db.mycoll2.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "docarr" : [ "doc1", "doc2", "doc3" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "docarr" : [ "doc4", "doc5", "doc6" ] }
//use aggregate to represent array documents linewise
> db.mycoll2.aggregate([
... {$unwind: "$docarr"}
... ]);
//ouput document from array, you can access each document via _id and docarr field label name
{ "_id" : 1, "docarr" : "doc1" }
{ "_id" : 1, "docarr" : "doc2" }
{ "_id" : 1, "docarr" : "doc3" }
{ "_id" : 2, "docarr" : "doc4" }
{ "_id" : 2, "docarr" : "doc5" }
{ "_id" : 2, "docarr" : "doc6" }
>
```